# Python, why is my loop writing a blank space to the end of the list from text file

Tags: python, list, loops

```
correctAnswers = ['A','C','A','A','D','B','C','A','C','B','A','D','C','A','D','C','B','B','D','A']

studentAnswers = []
correctList = []
file = open('forchapter7.txt','r')

student = file.readline()
student = student.rstrip('\n')
studentAnswers.append(student)

while student != '':

    student = file.readline()
    student = student.rstrip('\n')
    studentAnswers.append(student)

print(studentAnswers)
print(correctAnswers)


file.close()    

#displays this

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', '']
['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A']
```

my text file is a plain .txt file with the letters A-T going down and no space or new line after T, why is my loop writing the blank space?

Comment: Maybe there is an empty line at the end of the file?  Note that you test for that *after* the append.

Answer (score 1):

When you read your final line, `student == 'T'`, so the loop repeats itself.  When you try to `file.readline()` after you have finished reading the entire file, it returns `''` because there is nothing else to read.  You are then adding this to your list.

Just add a check for empty string before adding to the list:

```
if student:
   studentAnswers.append(student)
```

**EDIT:**
An alternative you could use is to read all the lines with `file.readlines()` and iterate over the list.  This will not run the loop an extra time:

```
for student in file.readlines():
    studentAnswers.append(student.rstrip('\n')
```

You can even use list comprehension this way:

```
studentAnswers = [student.rstrip('\n') for student in file.readlines()]
```

Note, however, that if the file does have an empty line these last two methods will need checks to prevent them from adding an empty entry to the list.

Comment: I tried something like this putting the check before it even read the line it makes sense now thank you.